# Why does my sum of odd Fibonacci numbers give incorrect result?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fibonacci

Q. Given a positive integer `num`, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to `num`.

My solution.

```js
function sumFiboOdds(num) {
  var fib = [0, 1];

  function searchFibo(i, limit) {
    if (i > limit) {
      return;
    }
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
    searchFibo(i + 1, limit);
  }

  searchFibo(2, num);
  return fib;
}

var res = sumFiboOdds(1000); //"num"

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < res.length; i++) {
  if (res[i] % 2 !== 0) {
    sum += res[i];
  }
}

console.log(sum); //answer is 11708364174233842, should be 1785!!
```

Any clue? Maybe it's Friday but I am not getting it?!!

Comment: The 18th fibonacci number is 1597: odd and above 1000. You are summing all the odd numbers in the first 1000 numbers. Not numbers <= 1000.

Comment: if you want to impress with modern javascript - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/jh61fmwk/ :p

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're gathering the first 1000 Fibonacci numbers instead of only numbers up to 1000.

```js
function sumFiboOdds(limit) {
  var fib = [0,1];

  function searchFibo(i) {
    var next = fib[i-2]+fib[i-1];
    if(next > limit) {
      return;
    }
    fib[i]=next;
    searchFibo(i+1);
  }

  searchFibo(2);
  return fib;
}

var res = sumFiboOdds(1000);

var sum = res.reduce((s, n) => s + (n%2!==0 ? n : 0), 0);

console.log(sum);
```